# MPAndroid Bar Chart Not Aligned with Labels

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
  int length = jsonArray.length();
  ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
  ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    entries.add(new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Potentials")), i));
    labels.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));
  }
BarChart chart = new BarChart(PotentialbySourceActivity.this);
  BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");
  setContentView(chart);
  BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
  chart.setData(data);
  chart.setDragEnabled(true); // on by default
  chart.setVisibleXRange(1,5);
  chart.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
  chart.setDescription("");    // Hide the description
  chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(true);
  chart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(true);
  chart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(true);
  Toast.makeText(PotentialbySourceActivity.this,"test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  chart.getLegend().setEnabled(true);
  chart.setDescription("# of Industry");
  dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
```

I am using a JSONArray to fill my MPAndroid Bar Chart. But the Bars are not aligned with their labels. Like [this](https://fbcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xlt1/v/t34.0-0/p206x206/12957185_573153892851777_736558725_n.png?oh=f66e170699eab5f30b29f04b5d829679&oe=570B20AD&__gda__=1460371708_33faf33737196195c61a97cfec4f0296) Can anyone help what can I do to align the bars with their corresponding labels?

Comment: Have you tried this
           XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
            xAxis.setEnabled(true); 
            nd INSIDE th
            // setting position to TOP ae chart
            xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP_INSIDE);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I have edited your code block to decrease the indentation to make it more readable. Please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information about formatting your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a lot of space between the labels along the XAxis and not all the labels were being displayed. The following property solved the problem.

```
xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(0);
```

This ensures that all the labels are displayed and the labels get aligned with the bars. You can then trim your label characters accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I used version 2.1.6 and there is no issues of alignment with labels. Please follow below example by replacing your bar entries and labels:

```
    BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(9f, 5));

    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");


    BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
    chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    chart.setData(data);
```

Comment: If you need further assistance do let me know I will help you mate. Happy coding :)